# Replace product image by a placeholder for specific category in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, product

Currently I am working for a client that has a tabacco/shisha website. In the Netherlands there is a new law coming where all pictures of tabacco cannot be shown anymore on websites. So my goal is to remove the product images of this URL: https://gecona.nl/product-categorie/waterpijptabak and replace the pictures with an image placeholder.

On Google I saw that this piece of code in your functions.php should help to remove the pictures:

```
remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10);
```

I added this line of code, but no images are being removed. I have searched on the internet for alternatives and fixes, but nothing works.

I would be very thankful if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

To display a placeholder as image for specific product category defined term, use the following instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_image_id', 'filter_product_image_id', 999, 2 );
function filter_product_image_id( $image_id, $product ) {
    $category_terms = array('waterpijptabak'); // <== Defined terms for your category(ies)

    if ( has_term( $category_terms, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ){
        return false;
    }
    return $image_id;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: I placed your code in the child theme functions.php. I changed 'waterpijptabak' to my category id: 60. Still all images show on my shopping page. Do you know what is going wrong?

Comment: @RobinBuren This code works as it's tested on last WooCommerce version using Storefront theme (and also works on any WooCommerce version since version 3). The fact that it doesn't work for you can be due to a lot of different things… This can be due to your theme, a plugin, to some other customization made by you, or a bad configuration… If it's a problem of child theme configuration maybe try to use the [plugin code snippets](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) instead of adding code into function.php file. Nobody can't guess and tell you why things doesn't work for you.